# Manually change file extension during save as

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

Excel save as.  I start with an .xls file and save as to a .csv file -Recently I've had to manually change the file name by typing over the .xls to .csv

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? If you select "Save As" csv it should set the extension for you.

Answer (score 3):

In Excel 2007 if you choose save as, other formats then dropdown the "Save as type" box, CSV is an option there. Don't know what version you're on but there should be a similar method for accomplishing it.

[image: Excel 2007: "Save as" in top menu]

[image: Excel 2007: "Save as type" drop-down in save as window]